# My Email on Office 365 didn't receive emails but it can sends

Tags: azure, office365, exchange-server

I purchased a domain on Azure and I connected it with another exchange server.

The email that i created on this domain can't receive emails but it can send any email and my subscription was disabled on Azure, so why i can't receive any emails on this domain ? and what is the solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Domain purchase through Azure are actually through GoDaddy, Azure (Microsoft) is not a domain registrar.

If you purchase through Azure if means Azure was hosting DNS for Domain and if your subscription was disable it means there is no DNS routing for domain.  You can confirm by using https://mxtoolbox.com/

You can send out because you do not need your Domain DNS to send out mail.

Check out information below, you might have to contact Azure Support to separate domain from Azure if possible.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/08/08/faq-app-service-domain-preview-and-custom-domains/

Hope this helps.